# When do you need to construct a new reducer?

Tags: redux

I am new to redux and i dont know when do i need to construct a new one

Comment: When you have new functionality...? Your question needs a lot more context. What do you mean with construct? When do you think it might be necessary?

Comment: I got multiple states to manage do i need to separate those to multiple reducers or shoud i put it all in one object and got one reducer to act on it.

Comment: As your application scales, you need more efficient ways to handle data consistency. And it becomes more difficult to manage state if you have many states in every component. It’s on you if you’re going to use redux or not. But in big applications with many components, it would be nice to have some reducers, so that you can have better readability and organization :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Style Guide recommends to [structure your application by feature](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#structure-files-as-feature-folders-with-single-file-logic) so you would usually create a new slice (and thus reducer) per feature.

But in the end it is entirely up to you and what you personally find most readable and maintainable.